# How to run Popcorn Time as simple user

Tags: permissions, streaming, torrent-client, opt

I just installed Popcorn Time following [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/popcorn-time-ubuntu-linux/).

When I run it as main user (the one who can use sudo privileges) without sudo, it works perfectly.

But when another user tries to run it from his session, this user can't play anything. The program runs normally at the beginning, but then it can't play anything.

When I run it from a Terminal, in both cases (as main user and as simple user), I get the same error code :

```
$ Popcorn-Time  [25376:25376:0117/112038:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(345)]
InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

The main user is in the `adm` and in the `lpadmin` groups, the other one isn't. The question is : how give the right to `users` group to run the program without problem ? In the /opt/ directory there is google-chrome installed and the "simple" user can use it without problem, as the sudo user does.

Thank you, in advance, for your valuable assistance.

Comment: You already know the differences - one is allowed to use sudo, the other is not.

Comment: If there is no other difference(s), why the first user can use the program and the other can't ? Should I try a chown -R command on the installation directory ?

Comment: Probably the `sudo` user is in one `group` that the other isn't in. Try `id -Gn [username]` for both users and see the difference.

Comment: No, leave it, and feel free to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command `sudo chown -R root:root /opt/popcorntime`

The 'simple' user can now play medias in Popcorn Time.